# Eclipse not resolving avcodec_send_packet()

Tags: c++, eclipse, libav

I am trying to decode a packet from compressed data coming from a mp4 container. I have gotten the AVCodecContext, and gotten the packet from avreadframe(). The problem is that when I try to decode a packet,eclipse keeps saying that avcodec_send_packet() could not be resolved.

I have included:

```
#include<libavformat/avformat.h>
#include<libavcodec/avcodec.h>
```

also the program is in c++ so I enclosed the include inside of extern "C".
I am on ubuntu 16.04. I also looked through avcodec.h and did not find the prototype for avcodec_send_packet().

Additionally, I have edited the g++ command to link -lavcodec -lavformat . I'm not sure what else to check. Other functions in avcodec work. Just not this one.

Comment: Probably too old version, see [New AVCodec API](https://blogs.gentoo.org/lu_zero/2016/03/29/new-avcodec-api/) dated the 29th of March, 2016

Comment: @cmacia06, Have you come around a solution? I'm running into the same issue..

Comment: Yes, I needed to compile and update the libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As J.J. Hakala pointed out, the libav libraries needed to be updated. After updating the libraries, just refresh eclipses index